# Oracle SQL Developer - tables cannot be seen

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was using SQL Developer 1.1. I have recently upgraded to SQL Developer 3. After the upgrade, I noticed that some of my connections do not show their tables. I can do a select on the tables and the data is shown. I can see other objects like views etc. I can still use my older version and can see all the tables listed fine for the same schemas. There are other connections that show up fine though.

Cannot seem to find information on this. I tried removing the filter but it didn't work.

Did anybody run into this? Please help.

Answer (score 62):

The tables you are looking for are probably in a different schema.  There are a couple of options.  You can either click on Other Users in the tree under your connection, or right click on the connection and select Schema Browser and then select the desired schema.

Comment: And what if you don't have a default schema to give your user, but you just want to see all of the tables and views that exist? Or, at least, all of the tables/views the account has access to?

Comment: I don't want to change the database under a different scema. The schema I want to change is the one that's not showing tables.

Answer (score 34):

Select 'Other Users' from the and select your user(schema), under which you will be able to see your tables and views.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Account I'm using doesn't appear here.  Why would it? It is not an "other" user, it is *the user* I'm *actually* logged in with.

Comment: what do you mean "your user". There's hundreds of users, none of which I would call mine.

Comment: In my case a table not in the list. I can query it, but "DESCRIBE" command returns an error. I suspect I have permissions to query, but not to see properties.

Answer (score 29):

I have tried both the options suggested by Michael Munsey and works for me.

I wanted to provide another option to view the filtered tables. Mouse Right Click your table trees node and Select "Apply Filter" and check "Include Synonyms" check box and click Okay. That's it, you should be able to view the tables right there. It works for me.

Courtesy: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: @vapcguy - Sorry to hear. I am afraid I wouldn't be able to help much since I don't have the right environment with me.

Comment: @Thayz  THANK YOU!    This has to be one of the single most useful answers I have ever read - you have actually provided a way for this to work like I expect it to - not like how Oracle seems to think is better.  They should have had this be the default view - and given the ability to turn it off!

Comment: No "Include Synonyms" in version 19

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem in sqlDeveloper64-3.0.4.34 and sqlDeveloper64-3.1.07.42.

According to https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2202388 it appears there is a bug in the JDBC driver having to do with 'Out Of Band Breaks' - basically a low level TCP issue.

The workaround is launch sql developer with JVM property **-Doracle.net.disableOob=true**
I tried this solutions for 3.0 and 3.1 and it works.

So I just quote here the solution from forum:

---

> *I believe I have identified what is causing these issues for some users and not others. It appears there is a bug in the JDBC driver having to do with 'Out Of Band Breaks' - basically a low level TCP issue. The bug seems to manifest itself in a number of ways. So far I've identified using shared connections (particularly with Vista or Windows 7) and connecting over VPN (any OS) as common scenarios. In all cases, not having DBA access is also an issue.*
>
> *First, let me explain why DBA access makes a difference. When we first access any particular data dictionary view, we first try to see if we can get access to the DBA version of the view (or is some cases tab$, etc). These views are much more efficient than the ordinary USER versions, so we want to use them if we can. We only check each DBA view once per session (and only when needed), but we can end up checking for access to a bunch of views.*
>
> *The OOB bug seems to rear its head when we do this check. We should get a nice, simple response back from the database. However, in the scenarios where the bug is occurring, this low level network bug is instead causing an error to occur that puts the connection into an unusable state. This then results in all the Connection Closed errors.
>   There does appear to be a workaround - the JDBC driver supports disabling OOB. However, doing so will affect the ability to cancel an executing statement, So I wouldn't recommend using the workaround in general, but it should solve the issue for the situations where users are running into this specific problem.*
>
> *To enable the workaround, a Java system property needs to be set **- oracle.net.disableOob=true**. You can set this in two ways. The first is to pass it in on the command line as sqldeveloper **-J-Doracle.net.disableOob=true**. Of course, that only works if you are normally running from the command line. You can also add a line to the sqldeveloper.conf file (located under +sqldeveloper\bin+). There the line would be **AddVMOption -Doracle.net.disableOob=true***
>
> *We are looking into additional resolutions, but for now the workaround should enable you to work with SQL Developer.*
>
> *- John*
>
> *SQL Developer Team*

Comment: fixed it for me, but this bug seemed to come out of nowhere, one day everything works, then the next day, no tables. thanks for posting! (and im on 3.2)

Comment: Solved my problem too! Thanks!
Using sqlDeveloper Version 3.0.04 under ubuntu 10.10

Comment: There is something wrong with our SOE and this fixes it. I've had to find this answer via google all over again a few times now!

Comment: I'm using version 19 and it's still not fixed. Obviosly they don't care enough to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

The answer about going under "Other Users" was close, but not nearly explicit enough, so I felt the need to add this answer, below.

In Oracle, it will only show you tables that belong to schemas (databases in MS SQL Server) that are owned by the account you are logged in with.  If the account owns/has created nothing, you will see nothing, even if you have rights/permissions to everything in the database!  (This is contrary to MS SQL Server Management Studio, where you can see anything you have rights on and the owner is always "dbo", barring some admin going in and changing it for some unforeseeable reason.)

The owner will be the only one who will see those tables under "Tables" in the tree. If you do not see them because you are not their owner, you will have to go under "Other Users" and expand each user until you find out who created/owns that schema, if you do not know it, already.  It will not matter if your account has permissions to the tables or not, you still have to go under "Other Users" and find that user that owns it to see it, under "Tables"!

One thing that can help you:  when you write queries, you should actually specify in the nomenclature who that owner is, ex.

```
Select * from admin.mytable
```

indicates that "admin" is the user that owns it, so you go under "Other Users > Admin" and expand "Tables" and there it is.

Comment: There's over 300 users. I'm not going to expand each one. Why can't you just tell me who create the table.

Comment: @PhilipRego If you are accessing the table via script, as I demonstrated, you already have that info. In Oracle, you need to know who the owner is, already, before you can access it.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. I don't have any scripts that specify the user in the statment. I don't have access to change the table and I don't know how to see who the owner is. I can only see the table with `select * [tablename]`

Comment: @PhilipRego I don't know how it's possible that you are able to access the table with `select * [tablename]` (you forgot the `from`, anyway) without specifying the owner, unless it's whomever you are logged in as that owns it.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't have access to one of the meta tables that SQL Developer 3 is querying. If I picked the right query, it runs the following SELECT statement:

```
select * from (
  SELECT o.OBJECT_NAME, o.OBJECT_ID ,'' short_name, decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
                decode(bitand(t.property, 64), 64, 'IOT',
               decode(bitand(t.property, 512), 512, 'IOT_OVERFLOW',
               decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912), 536870912, 'IOT_MAPPING', null))) iot_type, 
         o.OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, case when xt.obj# is null then 'N' else 'Y' end EXTERNAL
    FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O ,sys.tab$ t, sys.external_tab$ xt
    WHERE O.OWNER = :SCHEMA
    and   o.object_id = t.obj#(+)
    and   o.object_id = xt.obj#(+)
    AND O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
union all
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID , syn.SYNONYM_NAME short_NAME, decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
                decode(bitand(t.property, 64), 64, 'IOT',
               decode(bitand(t.property, 512), 512, 'IOT_OVERFLOW',
               decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912), 536870912, 'IOT_MAPPING', null))) iot_type, 
       SYN.TABLE_OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, case when xt.obj# is null then 'N' else 'Y' end EXTERNAL
              FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O, sys.user_synonyms syn,sys.tab$ t, sys.external_tab$ xt
              WHERE  syn.table_owner = o.owner
              and    syn.TABLE_NAME = o.object_NAME
              and    o.object_id = t.obj#
              and   o.object_id = xt.obj#(+)
              and    o.object_type = 'TABLE'
              and    :INCLUDE_SYNS = 1
)
 where /**/object_name not in (select object_name from recyclebin)
                         AND not object_name like 'BIN$%'
```

Try to run this statement to get a full error messages indicating which table doesn't exists (which is equivalent to "is not visible due to missing access rights"). SQL Developer will ask for values for `SCHEMA` and `INCLUDE_SYNS`. Set `SCHEMA` to your username and `INCLUDE_SYNS` to 0.

SQL Developer 1.1 probably used a simpler query that worked with your access rights.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I used the above query and it fails near sys.external_tab$. So I probably need to ask for permissions there. One of the posts in Oracle forums led me to the same conclusion earlier too. But your explanation is much more comprehensive. Thank you very very much.

Comment: On a later follow up, I found that I cannot access external_tab$ in connections that work fine as well. So the above given query is probably not the one SQL Developer users to show its list of tables.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this Issue by applying these steps

- **Tables => Apply Filter...**
- **Remove Criteria X**
- **Select Override Schema Filter**
- **OK**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solutions for you

1 - create new user with  All Privileges [how to create create new user with  All Privileges](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-grant-all-privileges-to-a-user/)

2 - now you can create tables as many as you want
[how to create tables](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-create-table/)

now you will be abble to see all tables,views,indexes ... you have been create

Answer (score 0):

The identity used to create the connection defines what tables you can see in Oracle. Did you provide different credentials when setting up the connection for the new version?

Comment: Nope, the user credentials are the same across both the versions.

Comment: Hmmm. Is this part of an overall upgrade (to Oracle 11.g perhaps)?
What kind of connections are you using? (TNS, Basic..)
Is your TNS file the same? (Trying to start with the basic stuff, sorry if you have already looked at these items..)

Comment: I m using a Basic connection type in both the versions. I dont know much about the TNS file but I did not do anything about it, so I guess that should not be the issue.

Comment: Just noticed something interesting.. the logging page shows something like "SEVERE 100 0 oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil Warning, unhandled exception: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" each time I am refreshing tables folder in the connections tree.

Answer (score 0):

3.1 didn't matter for me.

It took  me a while, but I managed to find the 2.1 release to try that out here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/index21-ea1-095147.html

1.2
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/index-archive12-101280.html

That doesn't work either though, still no tables so it looks like something with permission.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, but can read tables/values using the same account in SQLPlus, and through a .NET app that uses the 12c ODP .NET dll just fine - just can't see anything in SQL Developer.  Not likely permissions - at least for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

grant select on sys.external_tab$ to [myUser]; worked for me.
thanx Codo

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Mac.
Fixed it by uninstalling it AND removing the /Users/aa77686/.sqldeveloper folder.
Uninstalling without deleting that folder did not fix it.
Then redownloaded and reinstalled.
Started it up, added connections and it worked fine.
Quit it, restarted it several times and it shows the tables, etc. correctly each time so far.

Answer (score 0):

- open oracle sql developer tool
- go to **window** (at top menu bar)
- click on reset **window to factory settings**
  It is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Developer 3.1 fixes this issue. Its an early adopter release at the moment though.

Comment: I have the issue in 3.2.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this wound up being a permissions issue.

I solved the problem by creating a superuser role (`CREATE ROLE root WITH SUPERUSER LOGIN PASSWORD 'XXXXX';`) and then using that superuser account to connect to the database.

This obviously won't be a viable solution in all situations.

Answer (score -2):

You need select privileges on All_users view

Comment: Unless something is really messed up with your system every user will already have the ability to select form ALL_USERS.

Answer (score -3):

Launch SQL Developer as administrator

Comment: This isn't an administrator issue, it applies to accounts that should have access to databases they have access to, but logging into SQLD doesn't show them.